# I am new to protractor, followed the steps given in the official site(http://protractortest.org). Ended up with this error

Tags: angular, protractor, webdriver

I am just trying to do some basic automated e2e test using protractor. however i faced this error which i didn't find any answer to in the internet.

I have checked related questions asked and answered in stack overflow, none of them resolved my issue.

config file :
    ```

```
// An example configuration file
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    // The address of a running selenium server.
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
    },

    specs: ['./todo-spec.js']
    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.

};
```

```
spec file:
```

```
describe("Protractor Demo App", function() {
    it("should have a title", function() {
        browser.get("http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/");
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual("Super Calculator");
    });
});
```

```
error log:

Failures:
1) Protractor Demo App should have a title
  Message:
    Expected [object Promise] to equal 'Super Calculator'.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected [object Promise] to equal 'Super Calculator'.
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (E:\protractor\todo-spec.js:4:32)
        at <Jasmine>

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.047 seconds
C:\Users\M1049161\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:3190
        throw arguments[0];
        ^

Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
    at ProtractorBrowser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\M1049161\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:354:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\M1049161\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:4:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Can you check your protractor version with `protractor --version` in the cmd? If you are using the latest release (6) then the promise manager will be disabled by default and there is a chance they have not updated the documentation to reflect that. This would effect an example like what you are are seeing however?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve issue use following option**

1. Add **SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: true**, to your **configuration.js**

   **OR**
2. Use **await** in spec file as follows:

   ```
   describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
   it('should have a title', async function() {
       await browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
       expect(await browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
   });    });
   ```

Comment: adding SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: true didn't change anything. The second option worked though.

Comment: @RagasGnuluk : Could you please accept the answer by clicking on tick mark , as it seems that it resolved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with resolving the promise.Try the below one in your spec file .

```
describe("Protractor Demo App", () => {
    it("should have a title", async () => {
        await browser.get("http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/");
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true); // make true if your application is angular
        await expect(await browser.getTitle()).toEqual("Super Calculator");
    });
});
```

Hope it helps you